# Nested URLs not working with requirejs

Tags: requirejs

Using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/), I can use simple routes like `/register`, but I always get an error when I try a nested route like `/register/1` or something.

This works (where the route is just `/register`):

**`layout.js`**

```
define(['require', 'axios'], (require, axios) => {
  const layout = `
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="header clearfix">
          <nav style="padding-top: 10px">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-left">
              <li role="presentation">
                <a href="/"><h3>My App</h3></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
              <li role="presentation"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;

  if (window.location.pathname === '/') {
    window.location.pathname = '/home'
  }

  axios.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] = Cookies.get('token')

  return layout
})
```

**`register.js`**

```
define(['layout'], layout => {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/register') {
    console.log("Got it") // This works since the route is just '/register'
  }
})
```

This does not work (where the route is `/register/1`):

**`layout.js`**

```
define(['require', 'axios'], (require, axios) => {
  const layout = `
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="header clearfix">
          <nav style="padding-top: 10px">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-left">
              <li role="presentation">
                <a href="/"><h3>My App</h3></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
              <li role="presentation"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="/register/1">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;

  if (window.location.pathname === '/') {
    window.location.pathname = '/home'
  }

  axios.defaults.headers.common['authorization'] = Cookies.get('token')

  return layout
})
```

**`register.js`**

```
define(['layout'], layout => {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/register/1') {
    console.log("Got it") // Error
  }
})
```

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My App</title>
  <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css"
  href="/stylesheets/style.css">

  <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css"
  href="/stylesheets/registration.css">

  <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
  crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
  crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="/javascripts/styles/js.cookie.js">
  </script>

  <script data-main="config" src="require.js"></script>
  <script>require(['config'])</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="my-app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**`config.js`**

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'javascripts/views',
  paths: {
    allConversations: 'allConversations',
    conversation: 'conversation',
    home: 'home',
    layout: 'layout',
    loginView: 'login',
    login: '../scripts/login',
    logoutHandler: '../scripts/logout',
    memberProfile: 'memberProfile',
    profile: 'profile',
    register: 'register',
    conversationCount: 'conversationCount',
    nav: 'nav',
    axios: '//unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min',
    jquery: [
      '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min',
      '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min'
    ],
    bootstrap: ['//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min'],
    fontAwesome: ['//use.fontawesome.com/7973784de3'],
  },
})

require([
  'home',
  'layout',
  'loginView',
  'login',
  'logoutHandler',
  'nav',
  'register'
])
```

**How do I use nested URL routes with requirejs?**

Comment: I do not understand. Does code throw error? Or it just don't execute the condition's body? Can you `console.log` the `location.pathname`?

Comment: It doesn't execute the body.  It throws two errors, both of which point to my `index.html` file.  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` at line 1 of `index.html`, and `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` toward the bottom.  I'll paste my index file above.

Answer (score 0):

First problem. You are loading `config` module twice. `data-main` attribute specifies what modules should be loaded after the RequireJS load. So the second line is basically a duplicate of this

```
<script data-main="config" src="require.js"></script>
<script>require(['config'])</script>
```

Please replace this with just

```
<script data-main="config" src="require.js"></script>
```

Second problem, you have syntax error in `layout.js`. Your syntax looks like JSX, not regular JavaScript. Please amend this or use RequireJS JSX files loader plugin -> https://github.com/philix/jsx-requirejs-plugin

Can you please show use you `config` module?

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Removing the second line fixed one error, but the other error (`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`) remains.  `layout.js` is supposed to be that way.  I updated my post to include the full file.  I also included my `config` module.